# Pythonic way of doing so?

Tags: python

I wish to have the following simple algorithm implemented in Python.
Here is the pseudo-code for it.

```
for elem in myList:
    if only one elem satisfies myCondition:
        returns it
    if more than one satisfies myCondition:
        randomly return one out of them
    if none satisfies myCondition:
        randomly return any one
```

I surely can implement it in a C-style snippet. But I am here looking for **the most Pythonic way of doing so**.

Comment: So you have pseudo code -go write it in Python. What's the problem?

Comment: @MartijnPieters  Sorry for the confusion! Please see updated question. If many satisfy the condition, return any one out of them.

Comment: @MikeW  I've done it, but it is very long, a C-style code..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
return random.choice(filter(myCondition, myList) or myList)
```

Comment: Nice one; for Python 3, you'd have to use a list comprehension instead of `filter()` but this satisfies the OP requirements exactly.

Comment: @MartijnPieters so the `or myList` part kicks in only when none satisfies the condition? Also, how may I write the condition part? `random.choice(filter(>2??, [1,2,3]) or [1,2,3])`

Comment: @perfectionm1ng: if nothing matches `myCondition` then `filter()` returns an empty list, and the `or` operator then returns the second operand.

Comment: @perfectionm1ng: `or` short-circuits; if the first operand is true (a non-empty container or non-zero numeric value) then it'll return that, otherwise it returns the second argument.

Comment: You write myCondition as a function that takes an element and returns true or false. For example, if you want to pick a random odd number, perhaps `(lambda x: x % 2)`. Or "greater than 2" would be `(lambda x: x > 2)`

Comment: @MartijnPieters or you could just use `list(filter(...`.

Comment: is this the more pythonic way ? Guido !!!